# Creating an Iphone App without having an iphone? (with iphone simulators?)

Tags: iphone, c

I am wondering how good of an idea it is to start creating iphone applications without actually having an iphone?

I found that there are simulators for iphone...

Are they good enough or is it likely that I might encounter some problems down the road when creating an app?

-I don't have an idea of an app yet.

-I don't have a real iphone. There ARE some handsets in my job's office, though, but I don't want to use them too much.

Thanks! And if you think that it is an okay idea to create apps and test them on simulators, which ones would you recommend?

Answer (score 3):

Bad idea.

You can get a lot of work done but you really, really need an actual device to do your final testing.

Remember that it's a *simulator* and not an *emulator*. There are significant differences in performance. Lots of things work fine on your Mac but poorly on an real device. There are, perhaps surprisingly, a number of situations where the reverse is true (i.e., faster on the iPhone). You get better at figuring out these differences after a while, but without working on a real device you'll never know.

If cost is the main factor, you don't actually need an iPhone; you could work with an iPod touch instead.

Answer (score 0):

xCode has an Emulator in itself, so why not? All you need is a Mac-PC

check http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/ios_development_workflow/25-Using_iOS_Simulator/ios_simulator_application.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007959-CH9-SW1

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a mac?

iOS SDK has a really good emulator where you can try your apps, and i think if works on it, it should work on a real iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

Consider that the simulator is good enough, to create your app, but it all depends on what you use. For example if you use the accelerometer or the Bluetooth simulator is not suitable to your case. Overall, in many respects is very limited, but to begin with can go just fine.
To use the devices of which you speak, you must have a valid license from the developer and associate devices to your license, otherwise you will not use them (though not with the jailbreak)

Answer (score 0):

the iPhone simulator does not support everything, which is supported by a real device. Some things are impossible to test on a simulator, including but not limited to features/API associated with: calendars, camera, gyroscope, accelerometer, music, ...

Answer (score 0):

The iPhone simulator that comes with xCode is fine for the development of most applications. In my experience the area where it falls down is when you are dealing with stuff that runs in real time such as audio and graphics. The processor on the computer is obviously faster and if you are only testing on the simulator you might not realise that what you are trying to achieve is outside the capabilities of the device.

This could have impact on your frame rate (as you will get a higher frame rate on the computer) and in depth audio with lots of DSP faces the same issues.

If you are developing Line Of Business apps the simulator is probably all you need. Of course you need to test on a device before release, but most of the bug testing and debugging is possible in the simulated environment.